# Haskells data types and constructors with functions?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to Haskell and I'm looking at basic data types and constructors with functions.

I've done the below code:

```
data Name = Name String deriving (Show)
data Age = Age Int deriving (Show)
data Iq = Iq Int deriving (Show)
data Language = Language String deriving (Show)
data DataSubject = DSInformation Name Age Iq Language | DSConstruct {name :: String, age :: Int, iq :: Int, language :: String} deriving (Show)

makeDataSubject :: DataSubject -> DataSubject --Take in info and output a record
makeDataSubject (DSInformation (Name n) (Age a) (Iq i) (Language l)) = (DSConstruct {name = n, age = a, iq = i, language = l})

main = do 
  let x = makeDataSubject $ (DSInformation (Name "Ron") (Age 34) (Iq 100) (Language "French"))
  putStrLn $ show x
```

Runs fine, however it seems overly verbose -- how can I make to make it better?

Comment: Maybe this is an example, but your `DataSubject` type doesn't make much sense to me. What is the difference between a `DSInformation` and `DSConstruct` and why are they constructors of the same type? Why doesn't simply `DSConstruct` suffice instead of  `makeDataSubject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your `data` declarations can probably be simple `type` aliases.

```
type Name = String
type Age = Int
type Iq = Int
type Language = String
```

With these aliases, there is no significant difference (record syntax aside) between the two constructors for `DataSubject`. Get rid of one, and dispense with `makeDataSubject`. (Unless you want to encapsulate some logic or prevent pattern matching, you don't need a smart constructor to do what you are doing.)

```
data DataSubject = DS { name :: Name
                      , age :: Age
                      , iq :: Iq
                      , language :: Language
                   } deriving (Show)

main = do 
        let x = DS { name="Ron", age=34, iq=100, language="French"}
        putStrLn $ show x
```

If you do want real types, not just aliases, use `newtype` instead of `data`.

```
newtype Name = Name String deriving Show
newtype Age = Age Int deriving Show
newtype Iq = Iq Int deriving Show
newtype Language = Language String deriving Show

data DataSubject = DS { name :: Name
                      , age :: Age
                      , iq :: Iq
                      , language :: Language
                      } deriving (Show)

main = do
         let x = DS { name=Name "Ron", age=Age 34, iq=Iq 100, language=Language "French"}
         putStrLn $ show x
```

You might want to add a smart constructor here, but have it take each piece of data as a separate argument (wrapped or unwrapped), not a single argument that is already the return value up to isomorphism. (That is, your constructor was essentially the identity function other than some repackaging of the input.)

```
makeDataSubject :: String -> Int -> Int -> String -> DataSubject
makeDataSubject name age iq lang = DS {name=Name name, age=Age age, iq=Iq iq, language=Language lang}
```

or

```
makeDataSubject' :: Name -> Age -> Iq -> Language -> DataSubject
makeDataSubject' name age iq lang = DS {name=name, age=age, iq=iq, language=lang}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are running into one of Haskell's weaknesses: the record system. It would be nice if we had some sort notation to express `subject.name` and `subject.age` rather than destructuring explicitly but right now there is no good answer. Work coming down the pipeline in GHC 8 should address the problem soon, however, and there are are all sorts of libraries working in the problem space. But, for this question specifically, we can employ a simple trick: `-XRecordWildcards`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Main where

newtype Name = Name String deriving Show
newtype Age = Age Int deriving Show
newtype Iq = Iq Int deriving Show
newtype Language = Language String deriving Show

data DataSubject =
    DSInformation Name Age Iq Language
  | DSConstruct {name :: String, age :: Int, iq :: Int, language :: String}
  deriving Show

-- | Take in info and output a record
makeDataSubject :: DataSubject -> DataSubject
makeDataSubject (DSInformation (Name name) (Age age) (Iq iq) (Language language)) =
  DSConstruct {..}

main :: IO ()
main =
  print . makeDataSubject $ DSInformation (Name "Ron") (Age 34) (Iq 100) (Language "French")
```

By destructuring into the names of the fields, `{..}` will pick up on those bindings in scope to automatically populate the fields. You will *absolutely* want to turn on `-Wall -Werror` during compilation because it will be now more than ever easier to misspell something and forget to populate a field and then you end up with a partial record (another wart of the records system) where some fields are left `undefined`.